# Inserting dynamic data into tmp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to insert dynamic values into temp table? I have to predefined queries which are returning me results. My requirement :

```
DECLARE @F_SUM_CCYAMT NUMERIC(25, 4)
DECLARE @A_SUM_CCYAMT NUMERIC(25, 4)

CREATE TABLE #CB_TBL_CHECK (
    F_SUM_CCYAMT NUMERIC(25, 4) NULL
    ,A_SUM_CCYAMT NUMERIC(25, 4) NULL
    )
    /*Queries are here which derives value for the variable @F_SUM_CCYAMT,@A_SUM_CCYAMT */
```

Have to insert `@F_SUM_CCYAMT,@A_SUM_CCYAMT` into temp table to implement other logic.

Comment: Please expand your question, I've got no idea what the problem is.

Comment: What is `dynamic values`? will your table store unkown values?

Comment: Thanks for your quick turn . I have to insert dynamic values in temp table. The SP is having logic to derive the values for temp variable and have to store this variable data into temp table.

Comment: Show expected input and output for this to be clear.

Comment: We don't understand what are you asking. Every variable is dynamic, and every table (temporary or not) is dynamic. All of them can store different values. If you can't explain in another way - post expected result.

Comment: Had modified my question. Hope you all get my concern

Comment: something like that `insert into #CB_TBL_CHECK values(@F_SUM_CCYAMT,@A_SUM_CCYAMT)`. but you strongly have to read manuals for `INSERT` if you want work with SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass your variables as values in your insert statement. Try like this,

```
DECLARE @F_SUM_CCYAMT NUMERIC(25, 4)
DECLARE @A_SUM_CCYAMT NUMERIC(25, 4)

CREATE TABLE #CB_TBL_CHECK (
    F_SUM_CCYAMT NUMERIC(25, 4) NULL
    ,A_SUM_CCYAMT NUMERIC(25, 4) NULL
    )

/*Queries are here which derives value for the variable @F_SUM_CCYAMT,@A_SUM_CCYAMT */
INSERT INTO #CB_TBL_CHECK
VALUES (
    @F_SUM_CCYAMT
    ,@A_SUM_CCYAMT
    )

SELECT *
FROM #CB_TBL_CHECK
```